# Combining two programs into one while loop

Tags: python, project

So I tried combining these two separate programs. One is for measuring the temperature and the other is for scanning a QR code. When I tried this script, only the first program is being executed. Can you help me find what I'm lacking or any wrong indention or code I've placed? The two programs work just fine when separated. Note: in the separated script there was a 'while True:" before the if sensor == 0 in the second program

```
import board
import busio as io
import adafruit_mlx90614
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

import cv2
import re
import csv

from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN)

while True:
    sensor = GPIO.input(15)

    if sensor == 1:
        print("Scanning...")
        sleep(0.1)

    elif sensor == 0:
        print("User Detected")
        i2c = io.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=100000)
        mlx = adafruit_mlx90614.MLX90614(i2c)
        temp = "{:.2f}".format(mlx.object_temperature)
        sleep(0.1)
        print("Temperature:", str(temp) + "°C")
        
        if temp >= str(37.5):
            print("High Temperature")
        else:
            print("Normal Temperature")
        break
    
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # for second program
        detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector() # scanning QR code

        print("Reading QR code using Raspberry Pi camera")
        print("Please place QR code.")
        print()

    if sensor == 0: # second program starts here                  
        _, img = cap.read()
        data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
        
        if bbox is not None:
            for i in range(len(bbox)):
                cv2.line(img, tuple(bbox[i][0]), tuple(bbox[(i+1) % len(bbox)][0]), color=(255,
                             0, 0), thickness=2)
                
                cv2.putText(img, data, (int(bbox[0][0][0]), int(bbox[0][0][1]) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                            0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                if data:
                  sw1Press = False
                    
                  data = data.split(",")
                  today = date.today()
                  now = datetime.now()
                  current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
                  print("Name: " + data[0])
                  print("Age: " + data[1])
                  print("Address: " + data[2])
                  print("ContactNo: " + data[3])
                  print("Date: " + str(today))          
                  print("Time: " + current_time)
                  print()
                    
                  userScanned = False
                  if userScanned == False:
                     with open('List2.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
                          fieldNames = ['Name', 'Temp', 'Age', 'Address', 'ContactNo', 'Date', 'Time']
                          writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldNames)
                          writer.writerow({'Name': data[0], 'Temp': temp, 'Age': data[1], 'Address': data[2],
                                             'ContactNo': data[3], 'Date': date, 'Time': current_time})
                  print("Done")
               
      else:
         cap.read()
         cv2.destroyAllWindows()
led.off()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by the `break` statement in your code.  If `sensor==0` is true, the block containing this `break` statement will run, the `break` in that block will always be hit, at which point the `while True:` loop will be exited and any code below the `break` will never run.  The second program's code is below the `break`.  So it won't run when `sensor==0` is true.  But per the `if` statement that protects it, it will only be run when `sensor == 0` is true.  So the second program will never run.

Not only will the second program's code never run, but the code below the `break` in the first program will never run either.  Did you maybe mean for the `break` statement to be indented so it is only executed in the "Normal Temperature" case?  Since the two programs seem to be independent, I'm guessing that you don't want that `break` statement at all.

The most obvious way to fix this is to remove the break and possibly make the execution of the remaining code in the first program contingent on some condition.  I assume that this conditional is necessary because the only reason I can see to have the `break` in the first place would be to skip the execution of this code.  So something like this:

```
if sensor == 0:
    print("User Detected")

    ...

    if temp >= str(37.5):
        print("High Temperature")
    else:
        print("Normal Temperature")
    # break               <- @@@ break statement removed @@@
    if (????):  #         <- @@@ if remainder of this code should not always be run, conditionally run it or not.
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # for second program
        detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()  # scanning QR code
        
        print("Reading QR code using Raspberry Pi camera")
        print("Please place QR code.")
        print()
        
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # for second program
        detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector()  # scanning QR code
        
        print("Reading QR code using Raspberry Pi camera")
        print("Please place QR code.")
        print()

if sensor == 0:  # second program starts here
    _, img = cap.read()
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)
```

In this version of your code, the start of the second program will always be reached each time through the main loop.

A better plan would be to put the code for each of the two programs in its own function and then call these two functions in the outer logic.  If you did this, you could use a `return` rather than a `break` to cause all of the remaining code in the first program to be skipped.  This would have no effect on if the second function/program is run.

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. I must've not noticed the break. I will try to execute the tips that you have given me. Thanks for clarifying it. ~

Answer (score 0):

**assuming both programs work on their own**, try this

```py
import board
import busio as io
import adafruit_mlx90614
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

import cv2
import re
import csv

from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.IN)

def get_temperature():
    print("User Detected")
        i2c = io.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA, frequency=100000)
        mlx = adafruit_mlx90614.MLX90614(i2c)
        temp = "{:.2f}".format(mlx.object_temperature)
        sleep(0.1)
        print("Temperature:", str(temp) + "°C")

        if temp >= str(37.5):
            print("High Temperature")
            break
        else:
            print("Normal Temperature")
            break
def scan_qr():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # for second program
    detector = cv2.QRCodeDetector() # scanning QR code

    print("Reading QR code using Raspberry Pi camera")
    print("Please place QR code.\n")
    _, img = cap.read()
    data, bbox, _ = detector.detectAndDecode(img)

    if bbox is not None:
        for i in range(len(bbox)):
            cv2.line(img, tuple(bbox[i][0]), tuple(bbox[(i+1) % len(bbox)][0]), color=(255,0, 0), thickness=2)

            cv2.putText(img, data, (int(bbox[0][0][0]), int(bbox[0][0][1]) - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.5, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            if data:
                sw1Press = False

                data = data.split(",")
                today = date.today()
                now = datetime.now()
                current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
                print("Name: " + data[0])
                print("Age: " + data[1])
                print("Address: " + data[2])
                print("ContactNo: " + data[3])
                print("Date: " + str(today))
                print("Time: " + current_time + "\n")

                userScanned = False
                if userScanned == False:
                with open('List2.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
                fieldNames = ['Name', 'Temp', 'Age', 'Address', 'ContactNo', 'Date', 'Time']
                writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldNames)
                writer.writerow({'Name': data[0], 'Temp': temp, 'Age': data[1], 'Address': data[2],'ContactNo': data[3], 'Date':date, 'Time': current_time})
                print("Done")
    else:
        cap.read()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

while True:
    sensor = GPIO.input(15)

    if sensor == 1:
        print("Scanning...")
        sleep(0.1)

    elif sensor == 0:
        if (# condition that indicates we want temperature
            ):
            get_temperature()
        elif(# condition that indicates we want to scan a qr code
            ):
            scan_qr()
            break
led.off()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

where your condition to trigger which function to perform is most likely going to be hardware specific/reliant

Comment: Thanks it does work but I'm finding a way where I can join them into one While true

Comment: @arcturus okay so you're problem is that your program needs to do two different things when `sensor == 0` find a way to differentiate between sensors when `sensor == 0` and then execute the respective portions of code

Comment: @arcturus i have updated my answer to reflect this ^

Comment: I'm using a raspberry pi microcontroller along with some sensors, I will try this program and see if it works. Thank you so much @dbakr !!

Comment: you could also try doing something like `skip = False` before you start your while loop and then after the temperature sensor function is called set `skip=True` and make the condition for `sensor==0` to `if not skip` get temp `else` scan qr